# Counting the amount 2 digit numbers in C

Tags: c

I have a slight problem with a program in which I have to count the amount of 2digit numbers in a text file. The text file consists of both symbols(letters in this case) and numbers. This is what I got so far.

```
int main ()  
{  
FILE *fr;    
int digit;  
char num[256];     
 fr = fopen ("tekst.txt","r");  
   if(fr==NULL)
 printf("File cannot open");   
 return 0;  

 while (!feof(fr));   
 {   
  fscanf(fr,"%s",num);  
  printf("%s\n", num);  
}

/*9   
if(num==0)   
               digit=2;   
       else    
       for(digit=0;num!=0;num/=10,digit++);   
               printf("the amount of 2 digit numbers is:%d\n",digit);   
   */             
    fclose(fr);   


    system("PAUSE");   
    return 0;   
}
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Do you consider `04` (for example) to be a 2-digit number or a 1-digit number?

Comment: When posting questions about problems with your code, it's good to provide the code like you do, but it's also good to actually describe your problem. For example, what happens when you build or run the program? For some input, what output do you get and what output do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will count the two digit numbers in the file. It will count "(37)" or " 37 " but not "07".
To include numbers with leading zero change `&&  iTens >= '1' && iTens <= '9'` to `&&  iTens >= '0' && iTens <= '9'`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    FILE *pf = NULL;
    int iNumber = 0;
    int iCount = 0;
    int iHundreds = -1;
    int iTens = -1;
    int iOnes = -1;
    int iEach = 0;

    if ( ( pf = fopen ( "tekst.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        perror ( "could not open file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    while ( ( iEach = fgetc ( pf)) != EOF) { // read a character until end of file
        if ( iEach >= '0' && iEach <= '9') { //number
            iHundreds = iTens; // for each digit read, move digits up the chain
            iTens = iOnes;
            iOnes = iEach;
        }
        else { // non number
            if ( iHundreds == -1 // if iHundreds is not -1, more than two digits have been read
            &&  iTens >= '1' && iTens <= '9'// check that iTens and iOnes are in range
            && iOnes >= '0' && iOnes <= '9') {
                iTens -= '0'; // convert character code to number, '3' to 3
                iOnes -= '0';
                iNumber = ( iTens * 10) + iOnes;
                iCount++;
                printf ( "%d\n", iNumber);
            }
            iHundreds = -1;
            iTens = -1;
            iOnes = -1;
        }
    }
    printf ( "Counted %d two digit numbers\n", iCount);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Do you come from python?

```
if(fr==NULL)
 printf("File cannot open");   
 return 0;
```

translates to

```
if(fr==NULL)
   printf("File cannot open");   
return 0;
```

or rather

```
if(fr==NULL)
{
   printf("File cannot open");   
}
return 0;
```

so everything after the `return 0` is obviously not executed, even if `fr` is `NULL` or not.

Comment: That statement `Do you come from python?` made my day happy.